# How to inject a ConnectionFactory in a JAX-RS resource?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jax-rs, neo4j

My team is currently in the process of repackaging Neo4j webadmin console to make it usable as a Glassfish standard JavaEE web application. We build that on top of [neo4j-jca-connector](https://github.com/alexsmirnov/neo4j-connector).

We have already found a way to repackage the various web resources and serve them from our war. we now fight against the various REST endpoints.

Indeed, those endpoints all have their neo4j `Database` injected as `@Context` elements (see for example [RestfulGraphDatabase constructor](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-server/milestone/apidocs/org/neo4j/server/rest/web/RestfulGraphDatabase.html#RestfulGraphDatabase%28javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,%20org.neo4j.server.database.Database,%20org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.InputFormat,%20org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat,%20org.neo4j.server.rest.paging.LeaseManager%29)). We can access a Neo4J database through JNDI naming and @Resource injection. But, as we don't want to change any line of code of those REST resources, how can we inject the database in that JAX-RS resource ?

Can we do something in web.xml ?

Do we have to write a JAX-RS Application class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add custom @Context parameters, you must create a @Provider class (implementing Injectable) for each type you wish to inject. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897933/where-do-context-objects-come-from) question for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is used in http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-unmanaged-extensions.html so you can take a look at how the database object is inserted there, https://github.com/neo4j/community/tree/master/server ?