# Where do @Context objects come from

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I've been searching everywhere, but can't seem to find a clear answer...

What is the mechanism whereby a server (glassfish for my problem) injects actual objets that are annotated with @Context? More specifically, if I wanted to write a class that did something like:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyResource {
  @GET
  public String doSomething(@Context MyObject obj) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

then how would I do it? Where is it that the MyObject is instanciated, who does it, and how?

Edit: I've seen stuff like the following:

[Using @Context, @Provider and ContextResolver in JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047400/using-context-provider-and-contextresolver-in-jax-rs)

http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/ContextResolver-confusion-td5654154.html

However, this doesn't square with what I've seen, e.g. in the constructor of org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase, which has the following signature:

```
public RestfulGraphDatabase(
  @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
  @Context Database database,
  @Context InputFormat input,
  @Context OutputFormat output,
  @Context LeaseManager leaseManager )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write your own injection provider and plug that into Jersey - look at [SingletonTypeInjectableProvider](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/SingletonTypeInjectableProvider.html) and [PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider.html) - extend one of these classes (depending on the lifecycle you want for the injectable object) and register your implementation as a provider in your web app.

For example, something like this:

```
@Provider
public class MyObjectProvider extends SingletonTypeInjectableProvider<Context, MyObject> {
    public MyObjectProvider() {
        // binds MyObject.class to a single MyObject instance
        // i.e. the instance of MyObject created bellow will be injected if you use
        // @Context MyObject myObject
        super(MyObject.class, new MyObject());
    }
}
```

To include the provider in your web app you have several options:

1. if your app uses classpath scanning (or package scanning) just make sure the provider is in the right package / on the classpath
2. or you can simply register it using META-INF/services entry (add META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProvider file having the name of your provider class in it's contents)

Comment: If you're subclassing javax.ws.rs.core.Application, you can register the provider with `this.getSingletons().add(new MyObjectProvider());` in your Application's constructor.

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: Try these: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/SingletonTypeInjectableProvider.html

https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider.html

Comment: The classes were removed from version 2.0+

Answer (score 3):

I think I may be on to something...and if this works, Martin should get partial credit. :)

It appears that the @Provider class must implement the **com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable<T>** interface. However, I'm not sure that this is enough to actually have the @Context be injected. What's missing, is that we have to tell the ResourceConfig object of the web app about the @Provider. In the context of what I'm trying to do, and taking hints from neo4j-server, the remaining work boils down to:

- extending com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer, and overriding the configure method:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void configure(WebConfig wc, ResourceConfig rc, WebApplication wa)
> {
>   super.configure( wc, rc, wa );
>   Set<Object> singletons = rc.getSingletons();
>   singletons.add(new MyObjectProvider());
> }
> ```

- specifying that this container must be used in the web.xml deployment descriptor:

> ```
> <servlet>
>   <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet Container</servlet-name>
>   <servlet-class>com.blah.MyServletContainer</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
> ```

Comment: Oh, no - you don't need to do that. I've edited my answer to show how to register your provider.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `@Context` with a user-defined type like `MyObject`. It is for injecting types that jax-ws already understands. It is mentioned [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e516).

> [Chapter 5](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-520005) of the JAX-RS specification presents all the standard JAX-RS Java types that may be used with @Context.

You probably want to use something like `@FormParam` or `@PathParam` instead. See [section 2.3](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e247) of the spec for a description. Here is your answer, copied from that section of the spec:

> In general the Java type of the method parameter may:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type;
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument;
> 3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String) and java.util.UUID.fromString(String)); or
> 4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

Comment: Correct. You can only inject the 12 allowable object instances as listed here: https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/what-is-javax-ws-rs-core-context-httpheaders-and-uriinfo/

Answer (score -1):

See [chapters 5-6 of the JAX-RS spec](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-520005). That should tell you everything you need to know about it.

Comment: Does these documents say how to write such functionallity yourself? Which I understood was the question.

Comment: You don't. It's for framework components. If you want dependency injection, look for a DI container, like Spring.

Comment: Aren't link-only answers frowned upon, since the linked site's contents can change?