# Jersey custom Context injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

I tried implementing custom context injection just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897933/where-do-context-objects-come-from/10899513#10899513):

```
@Provider
public class DaoContextProvider extends SingletonTypeInjectableProvider<Context,Bar> {

    public DaoContextProvider() {
        super(Bar.class, new Bar("haha"));
    }

}
```

And here's my controller class, to witch I want to inject my context:

```
@Path("foo")
public class Foo {

    @Context
    private Bar message;

    @GET
    public String index() {
        return String.format("%s", message );
    }

}
```

But in response **message** is null.

I tried adding my context provider to singletons, as recomended:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        getSingletons().add(new DaoContextProvider());
    }
//...
```

But then my artifact does not even deploy, and provides me with this error:

```
Artifact server:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I would provide server.log, as described in exception, but I dont know where to find this log.

Comment: How is the `Foo` resource class currently being registered? In the same `ApplicationConfig` class, or through web.xml package scan property?

Comment: @peeskillet in application config

Answer (score 3):

The set returned from `getSingletons()` is unmodifiable. Instead we need to override the method

```
@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
    singletons.add(new new DaoContextProvider());
    return singletons;
}
```

Note though that a direct `Application` subclass is limited in functionality compared to the Jersey specific way. In Jersey, the preferred approach is to use a [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html) subclass (which is actually a subclass of `Application`). For example (you can use [`PackagesResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/PackagesResourceConfig.html) to scan packages).

```
@ApplicationPath("/webresources")
public class AppConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    
    public AppConfig() {
        // scans the package and sub-packages.
        super("package.where.all.your.resource.and.providers.are");
        getProperties().put("some properites", "to set");
        getContainerRequestFilters().add(new SomeFiltersToRegister());
        getProviderSingletons().add(new SomeProvidersToAdd());
        // see the ResourceConfig API for more methods.
    }
}
```

This will scan for `@Path` and `@Provider` annotated classes, so we don't need to explicitly register everything. Though some providers will need to be explicitly registered. Your particular provider doesn't need to be registered though. It i picked up in the package scan.

---

### UPDATE

Ok since you say you are using Glassfish 4.1, the first thing you should understand is that Glassfish 4 uses Jersey 2.x. So any Jersey 1.x dependencies/jars you have, you should get rid of them. Use only Jersey 2.x dependencies, and make sure that they are only compile-time dependencies, as you do not want conflicting versions making it's way to Glassfish, that already has a version of them.

What this means is that your current implementation of the `DaoContextProvider` will not work. The `SingletonTypeInjectableProvider` is Jersey 1.x class, and the Jersey 2.x runtime will just ignore it.

In Jersey 2.x there are a few ways to configure injectable objects. One way is to create a `Factory` for the object. For example.

```
public class DaoContextProvider implements Factory<Bar> {

    @Override
    public Bar provide() {
        return new Bar("boo hoo!");
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(Bar bar) {}
}
```

In Jersey 2.x, the API for `ResourceConfig` has change, and we can extend it directly. For example

```
@ApplicationPath("/webresources")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public AppConfig() {
        
        packages("com.stackoverflow.jersey");
        
        register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(DaoContextProvider.class)
                        .to(Bar.class)
                        .in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can see the `AbstractBinder`. That is how we register the `DaoContextProvider` with the `Bar` class. So now `Bar` can be injected to your resource classes.

The only Maven dependency you need to pull everything else in, is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Notice the provided scope, so that it does not get built to the war. If you are not using Maven, then grab all the jars in the [Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). Remember that you should make them only compile time dependencies. They should no get built into the war.

**See Also:**

- [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)

Comment: My **PackagesResourceConfig** class does not have **getSingletonProviders** method, but instead has a method with a similar name **getProviderSingletons**. I tried using it, also tried without it, but it did not work.

Comment: Also tried to override "getSingletons", didn't helped either. Maybe it's something wrong with my Provider class, or something wrong with **@Context** annotation?

Comment: Yea sorry for the miss spelling. But I tested both ways with Jersey 1.19 and they both worked fine. I tested with your exact code. And just to be sure, you are deploying this to Glassfish 3.x?

Comment: glassfish 4.1, Jersey 1.x

Comment: I might have mislead you, the **getSingletons** method probably worked, i tested it wrong. However the second method did not